# oop login register system | How to process two DB::getInstace method

Tags: php, oop

When I call two table with different name 
ex :

```
$a = DB::getInstance()->get('tbl_menu', array('flag', '=', 1));
$b = DB::getInstance()->get('tbl_submenu', array('flag', '=', 1));
```

Where I operate these method to count row
ex : `$a->count()`

the operation always processed $b variable because DB::getInstance use static method, so why I can process `$a->count()` and `$b->count()` to get different value from two table ?.

in my purpose how to change static method to dynamic method when method called ?

Sorry for my bad english. thanks

Comment: Only the `getInstance` is a static method which returns a `DB` object. This is called the singleton pattern. Only one instance of the class `DB` exists. The function `get` is non-static and will return data depending on provided arguments.

Comment: `$a = DB::getInstance()...` followed by `$countA = $a->count();` _then_ move on to `$b = DB::getInstance()...; $countB = $b->count();`. After which `$countA` and `$countB` should be 2 distinct values. However, it'd be best _not_ to use singletons all together...